# What is this hash function?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

I was reverse-engineering the archive file format used by an old game, and discovered that it hashed filenames using the following function (decompiled by hand):

```
int hash(char* filename) {
  unsigned int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  for(int i = strlen(filename)-1; i>=0; i--)
   char c = toupper(filename[i]);
   a=(a<<5)+(a>>25);
   b+=c;
   a+=b+c;
  }
  return a;
}
```

I'm wondering if this is anything standard, or if it's just something random picked by the developers.

Comment: Can you tell us what year is the game ? Quite modern random number generation functions are based on the same ideas

Comment: it looks similar to a Shift-Add-XOR hash, but with additional additions instead of XORing; see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx#existing for some existing hash algorithms

Comment: Looks like any old thumbsucked string hash function to me. `a << 5 ^ a >> 27` is quite commonly seen.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't represent any standard hash function, just simple 'hand-made'.